# iOS Accessibility focus won't leave keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have a modal view controller being presented. One of the subviews in this modal is a text field which uses a number pad keyboard when it becomes first responder. When using VoiceOver and swiping through the elements in the modal and the user focused on the text field, the number pad keyboard appears and accessibility focus changes to the 1 key. However, once this happens, the user cannot swipe OUT of the keyboard.

Since the number pad keyboard doesn't have a Done button of any kind, there aren't any hooks into the keyboard that can decide if the user is done typing. I have set each of the relevant subviews in the modal such that `` isAccessibilityElement == true`, I have set the view controller's ``view`'s`accessibilityElements``` to be an array of all these relevant items. Navigating around inside the modal is fine until the keyboard appears.

When the keyboard is up and the user tries to swipe left/previous when the 1 key is focused, it just makes a dull thunk sound as if there isn't anything to the left/above the 1 key. Tapping on any of the modal's elements makes a higher-pitched, but equally dull thunk sound as if there's nothing to be focused there.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Does anyone know how I can get VoiceOver to "leave" the keyboard? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hey. I don't believe you can swipe anything on your subview once your keyboard is up. You would have to dismiss the keyboard for VO to focus back to your view. Which makes sense right? You're focused on typing something on the textfield with the keyboard. If you want an easy way to exit the keyboard, I would add a toolbar with a done button like you mentioned.